# Variables in shell scripting

Tags: environment-variables

I want to find a variable whether its a integer or string.
I'm not able to phrase a right condition to check using if condition.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: In bash? I'm pretty sure it's variables don't have a "type"

Comment: @Xen2050 Variables can have attributes which are like a type -- namely array, associative array, integer, and reference -- but using the integer attribute is very rare. See `help declare` for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Variables in Bash have no type, so you need to check the content of the variable.

There is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash) on stackoverflow suggesting this:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $yournumber =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

Apart from the accepted answer I especially like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106305/7365127), as it works for scientific notation:

```
isnum() { awk -v a="$1" 'BEGIN { exit(1-(a==a+0)) }'; }
```

Comment: ... or simply `re='[^0-9]'` to check for the presence of any non-(decimal)-digit character